Compiling with CMake and mingw32
I’m currently trying to compile a program using CMake on windows (for  multiple reasons) so I downloaded the MinGW32 compiler. By doing the following command on PowerShell (admin):
cmake -G «MinGW Makefiles» -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=toolchain.cmake CMakeLists.txt

I created the toolchain file which I just describe the path to the compilers (gcc and g++):
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY) 
set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "F:/tools/MinGW/bin/mingw32-gcc.exe") 
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "F:/tools/MinGW/bin/mingw32-g++.exe") 

I also created the CMakeLists.txt having the strict minimum commands:
project(project_fmu) 
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.12) 
add_executable(test test_fmu.c)

The error I’m having is the following:
    CMake Error at Path/CMake/CMakeTestCCompiler.cmake: 

The C compiler mingw32-gcc.exe
is not able to compile a simple test program.

I tried a C code using this compiler without CMake and it worked.
I deleted the content of Build folder and it didn’t work and also added
set(CMAKE_TRY_COMPILE_TARGET_TYPE STATIC_LIBRARY)

to the toolchain file but the error persists.
Btw I’m on Windows 32 bits, having CMake 3.29.2 (Windows i386).

Do not describe the code you have written. Instead, add to the question post that code (toolchain and CMakeLists.txt).

Hello, I tried to make it as you asked, is this ok now ?

I asked you to add the code of your toolchain and CMakeLists.txt into the question post. You have added none code, only fixed some formatting. Normally, CMake is able to find compilers automatically. So specifying additional toolchain usually is not needed. Probably, you have some specifics about your environment, so that automatic compiler search doesn't work on your machine. But you told us nothing about that problem and specifics of your environment. How do you expect us to help you, if you don't provide needed details? The error message you got should contain more information.

Ok I get it, I provided the exact composition of both files. Hope the details help.

Please, add to the question post complete error message. Here you can see how it looks like.

"I deleted the content of Build folder and it didn’t work and also added" - According to the command line you use to configure the project, you are performing in-source build. With such build there is no "Build folder". Your question post contradicts to itself. Please, post the actual code and commands, and post actual output of them. By posting imprecise information you waste our time which we spend on solving non-existent problems and you waste your time which you spend on checking solutions which are not fit to your problem.

I'm working on a computer not connected to the network. I can't provide screenshots and I need to write again the content of my files here. I'm doing my best to provide informations, I'm not here to waste your precious time. I have the same error as provided in your link of the complete error message.
The command is the following :
cmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" -DCMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE=D:\Travail\Workspace\oui\CMakeLists.txt -Wall

I'm not sure whar you mean with "downloaded the MinGW32 compiler". There is the old MinGW and then you have the newer MinGW-w64. I suggest you use the latter. You can get a standalone download from https://winlibs.com/
